# Exclude one point from the RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, complex, regions

I'd like to ask you about the way of excluding just one point from this example:

```
myArg[z_] := Mod[Arg@z, 2 Pi]
RegionPlot[y > x && myArg[x + I y] <= Pi, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

I want to exclude the $z \neq i$ $\mapsto$ point $(0,1)$.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Excluding a point would look the same as not excluding it. Perhaps you want to exclude a small region around the point of interest? If so, would just placing a white `Point` be an acceptable solution to your needs?

Comment: Hard to remove just one point, but here's a fake plot: `RegionPlot[
 y > x && myArg[x + I y] <= Pi && Abs[x + I y - I] > 0.05, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 75]`

Comment: @R.M., I got your point. It's just for "educational usage" to show that $z \neq i$ is outside of  the domain of a function.

Comment: @J.M.isback., thank you so much. That's the most useful fake plot I've seen today ;).

Comment: But, did you understand what I added to your code?

Comment: @J.M.isback., you've added the surface outside the circle but `&&` operator did the job and it looks ok. I wanted to create just an image.

Comment: Nicely put. So, might I suggest answering your own question with this knowledge of yours?

Comment: @J.M.isback., thank you again. Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Credits to [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) and [R. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/r-m)

J. M. suggested drawing a surface outside the circle:
[image: a hole]

Using the `&&` operator he made the intersection of two sets:

```
RegionPlot[ y > x && myArg[x + I y] <= Pi 
&& Abs[x + I y - I] > 0.05, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image: another hole]

Comment: RegionPlot[y > x && myArg[x + I y] <= Pi, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {White, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{0, 1}]}]

Comment: @BobHanlon, thank you. Another useful example.